# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error with sqlserver on Crecordset:update call (DoFieldExchange)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mfc

I am using Visual Studio 17, SQLserver, Oracle. I am exporting data from application to SQLserver/oracle. Updating records to database batch wise, taking a fixed number of records, update and commit, then take another batch to update and commit.

Using CDatabase:CommitTrans, and Crecordset:update and DoFieldExchange

With oracle, its working fine, I commit transaction and then take another set of records and commit. In case SQLServer, this gives following error
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error" on DoFieldExchange function.

Till CommitTrans, it exports data to sqlserver, but after 1st committrans , it throws error and crash on Crecordset:update call

Comment: Are you invoking `BeginTrans`?

Comment: Yes.  Starting with BeginTrans  -> commiting 5000 records then  again beginTrans and commit. Keep iterating  till all rows got commited

Comment: I don't think it supports nested transactions... so if your calling beginTran within an already open transaction, that could be the issue..